# Exposing TCP service using nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress, activemq-artemis

I have a k8 deployment (using minikube) for ActiveMQ-Artemis. In this I'm exposing ports for broker(61616) and console(8161) both. Pointing the ports to service. It is working fine.
and also I configured an Ingress Controller for the console.

Service.yaml

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: artemis-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 8161
    name: http-console
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8161
  - port: 61616
    name: netty-connector
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 61616
  selector:
    app: artemis
```

Ingress.yaml

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: broker-ingress
  labels:
    name: broker-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: artemis.broker.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: artemis-service
            port: 
              number: 8161
```

I can access the activemq console when I hit `http://artemis.broker.com`
And now I want to expose the TCP port (61616) using NGINX Controller through which I can publish/consume messages to ActiveMQ queue using a TCP URL.

I found TransportServer in Nginx Controller to expose TCP.
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/transportserver-resource/
Can someone help me how to configure this TransportServer.

PS - I'm new to kubernetes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nginx Ingress** does not support **TCP** or **UDP** services

You can follow this guide the setup & expose the TCP service : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

Here is my **YAML** config file for **RabbitMQ** i have used

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  61616: "default/artemis-service:61616"
```

Make **tcp-service** config into **ingress-nginx** namespace or where your controller is installed.

Add the Port to **Nginx** **service**

```
    - name: proxied-tcp-61616
      port: 61616
      targetPort: 61616
      protocol: TCP
```

You will be able to connect your Broker with `NginxIP:61616` now from outside.

**Note if you are very new to K8s**:

If you are running your application inside of the same Kubernetes cluster you don't need to expose the Port, you can use the **service name** for internal communication & connection.

**artemis-service:61616** rest will K8s will manage DNS resolution etc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The clients are sitting on different servers so I have cannot expose service

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, I had to dig down a little, but eventually it is working now.

Comment: Hey @harsh-manvar what is the nginx-service? I installed nginx with the github script (kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.9.6/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml) . That created a service which exposes port 80 and port 443. How can i extend it to add the proxied-tcp-61616 that you added in your example?

Comment: Not sure, i guess if you follow this doc https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/ nginx ingress controller will have the two ports default, after that you have to edit it and it will point out to you svc running in namespace using configmap configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For this I also found a solution with `sslpassthrough`. As the TCP endpoint is SSL enabled I can create an ingress with `ssl-passthrough` annotation as `true`. And I access the endpoint something like -

```
ssl://url.com:443
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Service of type=ClusterIP and have an ingress on top of it to route the calls, you can expose your service as a NodePort.
Doing so the service will be accessible from the outside on `<NodeIP>: <NodePort>`

rewriting your service this would be:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: artemis-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8161
    name: http-console
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8161
    nodePort: 38161
  - port: 61616
    name: netty-connector
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 61616
    nodePort: 31616
  selector:
    app: artemis
```

Note that the type changed and nodePort has been added to each expose port.
You can have a different port from the service port.
The range of valid (node)ports is 30000-32767
You no longer need the ingress

Here if your minikube host ip is (e.g.) 192.168.0.10
your service will be accessible in tcp  on 192.168.0.10:31616

note 2: you may choose to use the ingress anyway for http and the console, just create two services one as you have done previously exposing the http port, and a second as nodePort.

In a local kube this is very effective, as there is less security concerns, and this remove the need for ingress nginx custom config.